# Can you keep pandas.dataframe.style fomatting when writing to a new/existing excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

Every quarter I get ~100 reports that I need to compile together and then apply conditional formatting to. I'd like to automate the task to save myself at least 1.5 work days. I am able to get pandas to construct the data frame I want and then apply conditional formatting with pandas.dataframe.style, but I when I write the data frame to excel, the conditional formatting is lost. Does anyone know a fix to this?

**Example data frame w/ styling:**

```
import pandas as pd
import styling_functions as sf

sample_history = {'Glycol wt%': [98.6, 96.7, 94.0, 99.1]\
                , 'Water wt%': [1.4, 3.3, 5.89, 0.9]\
                , 'HC wt%': [0.001, 0.005, 0.110, 0.001]\
                , 'pH': [7.0, 6.4, 8.3, 7.9]\
                , 'Chlorides': [89, 75, 51, 32]\
                , 'Iron': [3, 2, 4, 9]\
                , 'Suspended Solids': [10, 30, 29, 44]}

df = pd.DataFrame(sample_history\
    , columns=['Glycol wt%','Water wt%','HC wt%','pH','Chlorides','Iron','Suspended Solids']\
    , index=['July', 'May', 'April', 'Februrary'])

df.style.applymap(sf.pH_background, subset=['pH'])\
        .applymap(sf.pH_font, subset=['pH'])\
        .applymap(sf.glycol_background, subset=['Glycol wt%'])\
        .applymap(sf.glycol_font, subset=['Glycol wt%'])\
        .applymap(sf.water_background, subset=['Water wt%'])\
        .applymap(sf.water_font, subset=['Water wt%'])\
        .applymap(sf.hc_background, subset=['HC wt%'])\
        .applymap(sf.hc_font, subset=['HC wt%'])\
        .applymap(sf.cl_background, subset=['Chlorides'])\
        .applymap(sf.cl_font, subset=['Chlorides'])\
        .applymap(sf.iron_background, subset=['Iron'])\
        .applymap(sf.iron_font, subset=['Iron'])\
        .applymap(sf.solids_background, subset=['Suspended Solids'])\
        .applymap(sf.solids_font, subset=['Suspended Solids'])

print(df)

df.to_excel('formatted_samples.xlsx')
```

**Properly formatted data**
[image: Properly formatted data]

After I write to an excel file, the formatting is lost and all I have is compiled data. Help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can read about exporting pandas styles to excel [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel).

You can try setting the engine on `df.to_excel` to either `openpyxl` or `xlsxwriter` and see if that works (difficult to know for sure without access to your `styling_functions`):

```
df.to_excel('formatted_samples.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
```

Note that this method will only achieve *static formatting* of the output workbook.

If your goal is to get true excel conditional formatting you should look at the XlsxWriter module [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_conditional_format.html#ex-cond-format).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Juan. The styling functions will format the back ground and font colors based on the value passed to them. Here is an example of one:

`def pH_font(value):
    if value <= 6.0 or value >= 9.0:
        font_color = '#9C0006'
    elif value > 6.0 and value <= 6.5 or value >= 8.5 and value < 9.0:
        font_color = '#9C6500'
    else:
        font_color = '#006100'
    return f'color: {font_color}'`

Using a different function for each column's background and font yields the resulted screenshot I shared in my post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call to_excel on the Styler object created after all your applymap calls, not on the original DataFrame. So it should be either:

```
df.style.applymap(...).to_excel('formatted_samples.xlsx')
```

or:

```
styler = df.style.applymap(...)
styler.to_excel('formatted_samples.xlsx')
```